# 10.7.5 on a late 2009 MacBook Pro crashes

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

Ever since I installed Lion on my late 2009 MacBook Pro, it crashes several times a day randomly during some operation (open an application, browse the net, add photos, etc.).

I read the answer about updating Show Crash Prefs in System Preferences and tried to do it, but it doesn't work.

I updated Info.plist file with text editor exactly as in the answer, but the Finder still doesn't give the option of selecting new Show Crash Prefs?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following two troubleshooting techniques:

- download the latest Combo updater for your OS (note this is different than simply going to the Apple menu > Software Update) and reboot

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

- do a Safe Boot:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455

Then report back.

Answer (score 0):

Does Console give you any information about the crashes that appear at random? Console can be easily found with Spotlight.